# Loopback 4 querying SQL Server related tables

Tags: sql-server, loopbackjs, v4l2loopback

I'm trying to query a SQL Server database of related tables and return the data. Something like a person, address, and order table all connected by the personId. How exactly would I retrieve this data using the models?

Answer (score 1):

The TodoList example is a demo for the relation traverse between models.
See repository https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/master/examples/todo-list.

And tutorial https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/todo-list-tutorial.html

In the example, two relations are established: model `TodoList` hasMany `Todo` and `Todo` belongsTo `TodoList`.

To query a related model's data, first define the relation property `todos` in the todo-list repository:

```
export class TodoListRepository extends DefaultCrudRepository<
  TodoList,
  typeof TodoList.prototype.id
> {
  public readonly todos: HasManyRepositoryFactory<
    Todo,
    typeof TodoList.prototype.id
  >;

  constructor(
    @inject('datasources.db') dataSource: juggler.DataSource,
    @repository.getter(TodoRepository)
    protected todoRepositoryGetter: Getter<TodoRepository>,
  ) {
    super(TodoList, dataSource);
    this.todos = this._createHasManyRepositoryFactoryFor(
      'todos',
      todoRepositoryGetter,
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can call this.todos(todoListId).find(filter) to query the todo model instances with foreignKey equal to that `todoListId`.

See how the relation api get called in the controller function as an example: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/examples/todo-list/src/controllers/todo-list-todo.controller.ts#L61